# view and update form only for registered users

Tags: users, forms, user-access, user-registration

Requirement:-

I have created a Form in wordpress, which have some fields e.g., article name, article type, upload article, author name, etc.

Now i need, that only registered users can fill and updated form's information which they have filled.

Can this is possible via some plugin or other way.

Step 1:- User register on my website

Step 2:- after registration, when user login into site, he can fill a form (Only visible to registered user)

Step 3:- he can update the information any time.

Please let me know if this is possible in wordpress ..?

Thanks
Gaurav...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {

   /.../

} else {

   // your message 

        or 

   // redirect to registration form

}
```